# Unexpected exception with NSInvocation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, exception, nsinvocation

Following code throws an exception.

`vcClass` is a  `Class` object (inheritor from `UIViewController`). `Self` contains *my implementation* of `viewWillAppear:`

```
SEL viewWillAppearSEL = @selector(viewWillAppear:);
IMP viewWillAppearWithSuperIMP = [self methodForSelector:viewWillAppearSEL];
class_addMethod(vcClass, viewWillAppearSEL, viewWillAppearWithSuperIMP, @encode(BOOL));
NSMethodSignature *methodSignature = [vcClass instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:viewWillAppearSEL];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
[invocation setSelector:viewWillAppearSEL];
```

With message:

***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: index (1) out of bounds [-1, -1]***

Additional info: iOS5, ARC.
**Can someone explain me what's wrong?**

**UPDATED:**

This code code gives me **responds** message. So my class object is correct
    [vcClass instancesRespondToSelector:viewWillAppearSEL] ? NSLog(@"responds") : NSLog(@"not responds");

Alse Im getting crash right after `[invocation setSelector:viewWillAppearSEL];`. That's why I called topic title as *Unexpected exception with NSInvocation*.

**UPDATED2:**

Also *my implementation* of `viewWillAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    Class parentViewController = [self superclass];
    void (*superViewWillAppear)(id, SEL, BOOL) =(void(*)(id, SEL, BOOL))class_getMethodImplementation(parentViewController, _cmd);
    superViewWillAppear(self, _cmd, animated);
    NSLog(@"view will appear with super");
}
```

Comment: It means you have the wrong class in `vcClass`, and it didn't implement that selector.

Comment: `[vcClass instancesRespondToSelector:viewWillAppearSEL] ? NSLog(@"responds") : NSLog(@"not responds");`

Returns **"responds"** message

Comment: @lxt no, he wants to use the vc, not the view -- also I don't see a mistake in the 4 lines shown above. it crashes when you setArgument

Comment: are you sure `methodSignature` is not `nil`?

Comment: @newacct, yes. Also print description gives a lot of lines heading with "number of arguments = 3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is the type encoding that you are passing to `class_addMethod()`. This type encoding must include: 1) the return type, 2) the types for `self` and `_cmd` (the first two hidden parameters), and then 3) the types of all the other parameters.

For a method like `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, the type encoding should be the string

`v@:c`

- `v` -- for `void`, return type
- `@` -- for `id`, type for `self`
- `:` -- for `SEL`, type for `_cmd`
- `c` -- for `char`, this is what `BOOL` is. This is what you get when you did `@encode(BOOL)`

Answer (score 1):

BOOL *arg1;

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:methodSignature];
[invocation setSelector:viewWillAppearSEL];
[invocation setArgument:&arg1 atIndex:2];   // argument indexing is offset by 2 hidden args
```

Comment: Сan u please comment your answer?

Comment: that's the issue for sure. -viewWillAppear: accepts 1 argument, and invocation doesn't contain any

Comment: @art-divin, And?
Im getting exception right after `[invocation setSelector:viewWillAppearSEL];`

Comment: set the second argument as specified in this answer so your invocation will contain enough data to actually invoke the method

Comment: @art-divin: you are completely misunderstanding what the OP is saying. He is not getting the exception on trying to run the invocation. He is unable to set a selector in the first place.